# Transparent material acting wrong when in object mode

Tags: edit-mode, transparency, object-mode

It's hard to explain, would be the best to show you

[image]
[image]

In the first image i'm in the object mode when everything is deselected, as you can see i can only see a back fan and some random shape, while what I should see is when i'm in object mode, when that front panel is selected or when i'm in edit mode. Why is this happening?

Comment: Hello :). Just a guess - this could be caused by modifiers disabled only in edit mode.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)